# jquery - Lookup values on change

Tags: jquery

I want to post back to the server to run a lookup function.  So when a user types their email address into a textbox and "clicks out" I want to call my C# function:

```
UserInfoObject LookupUserInfo(string Email)
{
  //...
}
```

My jQuery abilities are not very good.  So, I could use some help setting up the basic structure.  The [API](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) is overwhelming.  Do I need ajax? Custom AJAX seems a little too advanced for my skill level.

In my overly simplistic view:

```
$('#textBox').OnChange(function {
    //call some C#

    //Use object info to populate textbox2 and textbox3
}
)};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic skeleton:

#### HTML

```
<input id="emailAddress" ... />
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(function () // when the DOM is ready
{
    var $email = $('#emailAddress'); // grab a reference to the input

    $email.blur(function () // when the input loses focus, do the following:
    {
        var email = $(this).val(); // grab the value in the input
        $.get('some/url/here',     // use ajax to send an HTTP GET
              {email: email},      // with the email value in the URL parameters
              function (data)      // and process the data accordingly
              {                    // when the response comes back
                  /*
                  * do something to populate the textboxes here
                  */
              });
    });
});
```

#### APIs used

- [`$()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery#jQuery3)
- [`.blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur)
- [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val)
- [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Comment: Hell of an answer.  Plus, I'm a huge fan of the 8 bit avatar.

Comment: This works great on my local machine. When deployed to the dev server it stops working. I popped open fiddler and I see 0 http traffic onChange. Any ideas?  Running IE7 (tried FF too, same problem).

Comment: Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) to check that it's sending the `$.get()` to the right URL. Are you requesting a URL from a different domain? If so, that's prohibited by the browser's [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), unless you're using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP).

Comment: turns out this has something nutty to do with ASP.NET MVC 3.  I posted a new question about it on SO.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could create an ASP.NET Page Method and call that via jQuery.

There's a great guide on [Encosia](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) which shows you how.

You can then attach a `blur` handler to your textbox, like so:

```
    $('#yourEmailTextBox').live('blur', function(){
         // ajax call to get data and fill form here
    });
```

Comment: Inline event handlers are bad for so many reasons, please don't use them.

Comment: Yes, removed my downvote. :) Though you don't have to wait for $(document).ready( ... ) when you bind events using live: http://api.jquery.com/live/ "Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future."

Comment: Good info for general, I'm using MVC framework so this won't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do need ajax and its not that tough to begin with. you just have to hook up the blur function of that input and send an ajax call to the server. you can do this like this

```
$("#InputBoxID").live("blur", function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://www.someone.com",
        type:"post"
        data:{email:$(this).val()},
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data)
        {
           // you can send data in json format from server and here you can use it like
           alert(data.FirstName);
           alert(data.LastName);
        }   
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use jquery .get or .post . that will be easier than .ajax

This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to:

```
$.get('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#textbox').live('blur', function() {
     var url = '/controller/LookupUserInfo/?Email=' + $(this).val();
     $.get(url, function(data) {
         $('#textBox2').val(data);
     });
 });
```

You could use Url.Action or any other helper method to get a well formed url. Get is really a short hand call over the ajax with a leaner syntax.